# this declaration has no storage class or type specifier in union

Tags: c++, unions

I declared the static variable a in union and assigning it with 9 and I want to display 9 but it gives compiler error at "a = 9"  this declaration has no storage class or type specified

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

union A{

    static int a; 
     a = 9; 
};
int main()
{
    A a; 
    cout<<a.a;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you think that the assignment `a = 9` in the union body should do? Do you actually want to initialize `a`?

Comment: Does this answer your question?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7751315/14273548

Comment: I am using book C++ Reference and there is  a line written "No static variables can be members of a union." I just wanted to test that

Comment: I think you need to learn the difference between initialization and assignment.

Comment: Your book is wrong.

Comment: @MridulRajbhar Which book is that? Could you provide its authors, name, edition, and publication year? AFAIK, unions may have static member variables.

Comment: @molbdnilo oh yes it is assignment.

Comment: @DanielLangr Book Name: "C++: The Complete Reference, Fourth Edition" author= "herbert schildt"

Comment: IIRC, Schildt has been well known for writing awful books full of errors since the 1990's

Comment: @MridulRajbhar Why are you learning C++ from a book published 18 years ago???

Comment: @DanielLangr can u suggest a good book ?? it Will be great help

Comment: @MridulRajbhar Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list.

Answer (score 0):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7751242/does-a-union-always-have-default-value-of-zero) about the initial value ("default constructor") of a `union`, and see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15996877/14273548) about static values in a `union`, also, you can accomplish initializing the union like so:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

union A {
    int a;
};

union B {
    static int b;
};

int B::b;

int main() {
    A a{9};
    cout << a.a << endl;

    B b;
    cout << b.b << endl;
    B::b = 18;
    cout << b.b << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```sh
$ ./union
9
0
18
```

Comment: You likely missed that OP wants to create a `static` member variable.

Comment: Added an example of static member @DanielLangr